# Passing command line argument in Makefile (tcsh syntax)

Tags: makefile, tcsh

```
HUB ?= HUBHA
if (${HUB}, HUBHA) then
    profile = example_profile_ha.txt
elif (${HUB}, HUBC) then
    profile = example_profile_c.txt
else
    profile = example_profile.txt
endif
hubname ?= ${HUB}
```

I want to pass value of HUB through command line, how to do that?

Comment: Please fix the formatting: you need to use a block code not use backquotes.

Comment: Is there a reason `make HUB=foo` doesn't work?

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and format your code such that it is readable. And also specify which version of make you use.

Comment: make HUB=foo? you mean keeping foo as default? Also is the format okay now?